# Problema com porcentagem e float: right

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Olá. Eu preciso fazer um menu com icones para ficar a direita do `Header`. Os icones são `divs` com `background-image`, e as medidas são relativas e em porcentagem (%). A ideia é que os icones cresçam conforme a resolução. Eu tenho um search box a esquerda do menu com a propriedade `display: inline-block`, e seu container com `text-align: center` para deixar o campo de pesquisa sempre ao centro. O problema é que quando declaro o `float: right` ao menu dos icones, os icones não crescem conforme a porcentagem declarada. Quando tiro o `float: right`, ai sim, os icones crescem conforme as medidas em porcentagem, mas ele não fica a direita da tela. Segue a imagem e os códigos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
/* Container do Comp. SearchBox */

.header__boxSearch {
 height: 30px;
    width: 19.53125%;
    min-width: 180px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

/* SearchBox */

.boxSearch {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
    
    .boxSearch__input {
        height: 100%;
        width: 75%; 
        float: left;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    }

    .boxSearch__btn {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        padding-top: 2px;
        width: 25%; 
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
        border-left: none;
        border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
/* Container do menu icon e icones */

.iconsHeader {
    width: 15.13671872%;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 170px;
    float: right;
}

    div[class*="navIcon"] {
        width: 2.44140625%;         
        min-width: 25px;
        min-height: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 2.44140625%;
        margin-left: 9.765625%; 
        float: left;        
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-size: cover; 
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .navIcon--Feed {
        background-image: url(../img/feed.png); 
    }

    .navIcon--Profile {
        background-image: url(../img/perfil.png);
    }

    .navIcon--Notification {
        background-image: url(../img/notificacao.png);
    }

    .iconOut { 
        width: 1.46484375%;
        min-width: 15px;
        min-height: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 1.46484375%;
        margin-left: 9.765625%;
        float: left; 
        background-image: url(../img/sair.png); 
        background-size: cover; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!-- SearchBox -->         
<div class="header__boxSearch">
    <div class="boxSearch">
        <input type="text" class="boxSearch__input" placeholder="Pessoas..."/>
        <button class="boxSearch__btn">                                  
        </button>
     </div>            
</div> 

<!-- Menu de icones -->
<div class="iconsHeader">
   <div class="navIcon--Feed">
   </div>                    
   <div class="navIcon--Profile">
   </div>
   <div class="navIcon--Notification">
   </div>
   <div class="iconOut">
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Alguem sabe???!

Comment: Não posso te responder 100% disso, mas creio que como a DIV pai não varia, as divs filhas não vão ter variação de tamanho baseado em %. Se você botar em cada um dos seus ícones, um tamanho de width e height baseados em unidade `vw`, creio que eles vão variar seus tamanhos.

Comment: @LeonFreire. Obrigado, vou pesquisar sobre. Porem, estou tendo problema com o float e porcentagens. Em outros lugares no codigo, onde as divs pais tem a propriedade float, as divs filhas não respondem normalmente aos valores em %, ou talvez a medida seja relativa a outros valores que não o widht, talvez ao font-size do pai. Não sei...

Comment: @LeonFreire, deu super certo. Muito obrigado! Você saberia me dizer se vw são amplamente suportados, e o calculo para converter px em vw. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Opa! Ainda bem que deu certo então! `vw` é amplamente suportado exceto pelo IE que passou a ser suportado apenas a partir da versão 11. Mas o que acontece é que ele é uma unidade baseada na largura da tela. `vw` significa Viewport Width, ou seja, é basicamente um percentual do tamanho da tela. Existe também o `vh`, que como você pode adivinhar, funciona da mesma forma, só que baseado na altura (Viewport Height).